# angular active link navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Angular beginner here. I'm trying to basically have my link be active once I'm on a given page. Found quite couple of examples none of which work, so it must be that I'm doing wrong.

This is what I've been trying (controller) :

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $('body').addClass('homepage');

    $scope.isActive = function(route) {
      return route === $location.path();
    }
  }]);
```

Html :

```
<li "ng-class" = "{active:isActive('/') || isActive('/home')}"> 
Home
</li>
<li "ng-class" = "{active:isActive('/about')}"> 
About
</li>
<li "ng-class" = "{active:isActive('/contact')}"> 
Contact
</li>
```

Application itself :

```
var app = angular
    .module('MyApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'templates', 
        'ng-token-auth'
    ]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'contact.html',
                controller: 'ContactCtrl'
            })
            .when('/about', { 
                templateUrl: 'about.html', 
                controller: 'AboutCtrl' 
            })
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });
    }])
```

So no matter on which page I'm located at, the `ng-class` does nothing with no errors in the console. However if I do this for home:

```
<li "ng-class" = "{active:true}"> 
    Home
    </li>
```

Then I get active class on my link, and this is the output :

```
<li ng-class="{active:true}" class="active">
Home
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't it interpolate the function isActive as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the logic to check the active link inside your `HomeCtrl` as it is one of the routes. When other routes are loaded there is no `HomeCtrl` loaded.

There should be controller defined outside the ng-view, such as `RootCtrl`. The `isActive` function should be added to it.

Since the child view scope would have access to parent scope, you can use the `isActive` in the child views normally.

Update:
Consider the html

```
<body ng-controller='RootCtrl'>
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Add the isActive function on the `RootCtrl`.

Comment: @Chadremani can you illustrate that with example, I'm not sure I follow. First of all I don't have RootCtrl